# I would like a "defer" function on review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-page

when there is more than one entry in a review queue, i sometimes would like to
defer consideration of an entry until later, but look at entries that come after
it in the queue.  this possibility isn't available -- "skip" permanently removes
the entry from consideration.

this "question" is a followup to [How to deal with robo-reviewers?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4541/579), which nicely covers the
options that *are* available.

Comment: I appreciate this idea as useful, as well as the chance to revise own reviews, perhaps due to errors etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a less hack-ish (but still suboptimal) way: If you don't want to take an action, go back to the list of review queues (using the "back" button or by clicking on the "Review" link on the top left). 
The post you were just looking at will be temporarily removed from the queue, so if you select it again, you will see a different post. (I don't know at what point the "skipped" question reappears in the queue; from what I've seen, I'd guess 15 minutes or so. EDIT: I just tested it; seems more like 5-10 minutes)

Comment: good find!  (i wonder if this is documented anywhere.  don't have time to check now; am clearing the decks to head off to the tug meeting.)

Comment: I was trying to find some mention of it on Meta.SE (while waiting for the queue to reset), but didn't find anything. I'll try again later and add a link if I'm successful. (Have a safe trip!)

Comment: I still haven't found an explicit announcement, but I now believe this is a consequence of the mechanic that avoids concurrent review actions (i.e., a robo-reviewer acts on the post you are carefully considering): If you are presented a post for review, it is (temporarily) removed from *everyone's* review queues -- even your own.

Answer (score 5):

A few weeks ago, [we added the ability to see reviews you've previously skipped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/131713). If I understand this request right, the existing skip option now behaves like the defer option you were asking for, so this request is now obsolete (or, if you're feeling charitable, completed).

Comment: ome more question before i'm willing to be charitable.  i had to search around a bit before i figured out exactly *how* to access the (my own) history, but it's there.  since reviews do get completed pretty fast here, there are some items that it seems i really would have liked to take a look at, but unless i've taken explicit action (vote or skip or edit or ...), those items never appear on my list.  is there a straightforward way to find those?  (i'll keep looking though, and will probably in the end decide that charity is due.  stay tuned, please.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm a little confused about how this can even happen. Are you looking for posts on which you used one of the workarounds above? Or do the posts in question have something else in common?

Comment: sometimes, knowing that there's just one item in a review queue, i don't "act" on it, but just drop out of the review queue with the back arrow, or click on "questions" to get back to the main thread.  also, there are times when i'm not on line for some days, and i know (by the pattern of avatars reported for the various queues) that there has been activity that i haven't been present for.  *those* are the items that don't show up in "my" history list.  (does that make more sense?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yep, I see what you mean now. At first glance, that sounds like a bug to me; I would expect the system to show you those reviews again later. Do you happen to know of any specific cases where this happened (excluding cases where the reviews were completed by other people before you returned)?

Comment: sorry, i can't pin down any particular items.  and it's quite plausible that the reviews were completed by other people before i returned; that's actually what i assume happens in most cases.  if that's the case, then i suppose it's "by design", and too bad.  (but it *would* be nice to have the ability to know what's happening under the covers.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You should have more than enough rep to access the review histories (I think it's granted by the privilege "Access to Moderator Tools" at 10,000 rep): If you enter one of the review queues, there's a link "history" on the top right (on the same level as, e.g., "Review | First Posts"). This view shows you *all* review actions, not just your own.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hack-ish way to defer your review:

1. Remember the URL (copy-and-paste it somewhere), and click Skip. While this will remove it from the review queue view (since it's been skipped) you can still access the review via the copied URL. When you're ready to re-review the item, paste the stored URL;
2. Click the Skip button but remember the post involved in the review. When you want to re-review the item, find it in the review queue history and click on any review choice made by a reviewer.

Option (2) is similar to (1) since they both point to the same URL.