# Reviewers; what do you eat for breakfast?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Ahem, this is going to be a rough one, so it's gonna be a long one too ala Pascal's famous quote. First, some context; we have

[How to deal with robo-reviewers?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/)

[Should we have a Grace period to avoid premature Voting to Close and Reopening Cycle](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4045/)

(and more)

This thing is bothering me for some time already, especially after the migration of many users who do more or less exclusively reviewing on the site but not much of actual content contribution. Not that I am dismissing or underestimating the effort that goes in but there is a fine line between having a lust-driven relationship with review buttons and actually reviewing the questions properly (which means once in a while clicking that $%$%^#& **Skip** button if you don't have any idea about the subject).

Fun fact; I have tried a few identification experiments such that I found a recently closed question and then voted for reopening (i've chosen closed-with-valid-reasoning ones to maximize the effect) and some users who actually voted for closing also voted for reopening. Now no need for calling names for this but, if you excuse my French, this is bullock-cart-pulling-bullshit (emphasis is mine).

Now, I don't know why you hang out here but I like being borderline useful while learning a lot. Also, as a recent-beginner of Python and Linux, I really feel the pain of some of the users that ask quick questions with haste because sometimes you really don't know what else to do and having copy/pasted every damn solution on SO or any other place, it quickly becomes a mess. Last thing you need is to put *n*-propeller-powered-jetillion nuances/rituals about what the site rules are or whatever the forum owners' girlfriend implemented somewhere. With a little bit of effort and gentle nudges, most new users give in without any sour feeling and make a MWE, it takes time and patience and we have a lot of it in here. Or had. Now all I see is dictating comments on how things operate here and *if you don't obey my warning, I'll call my mod brother and he'll whoop yo ass.* attitude.

Hang on; another thing needs to be out-of-the-way; There are these things called Stackexchange network rules, nobody knows who come up with them and why but in their own environement they make sense (I hope). And through some law-abiding-never-law-questioning citizens of that network we are introduced to these things.

For a recent one that claims that I'm not informed well about a site that I'm not even registered see [Consensus vs accepted answers on meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/)

However, if this means that powers that be actually dictate what we are doing here then, first, it goes against the notion of community-driven Q&A site, second, I am out of this place, in the first instance (which has no impact of course but I'm out anyway). It bears no threat value just my opinion. The reason is that I didn't sign up for this, and truly I don't care what owner of SE network thinks about TeX-SX. All I know is that, there are users who really dedicate their time and patience to come up with the wittiest solutions that we all see and also there are these review-people who click on the buttons like crazy in the name of some obscure nonsense that is maybe applicable to a humongous site that is called Stackoverflow that bares no resemblance to this site, I mean, in any possible statistical aspect.

My argument goes like this;

- Our number of question intake is not changing dramatically, so we were OK with not closing every question in 2 hours --> We will be OK without closing them in 2 hours
- Our number of active users is amazing including those review-junkees, even spams don't last longer than a few 5-minutes --> No need to fear about the unanswered/asked ratio, we are doing pretty good without closing them like crazy.
- New users were getting confused already with stock comments --> Now they are more pissed off in average (based on my observation so no facts here) But this question [Why is \rotate useless in deluxetable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200168/) believe it or not closed twice! Not once. We reopened it David wrote an answer and we closed it again. (The OP mentioned closing already but no we have to be faster, modern world doesn't wait, so in your face noobie, don't come back again)
- The close voters don't read the comments or any discussion going on under the question or answers. To be honest they don't read at all as far as I understand.
- This sucks.

These close-voting-users however become the unofficial saint-of-the-noobs when they vote for suggested edits. Suddenly every edit ranging from very good ones to oh-it-was-my-screen-having-dust-not-an-actual-comma type of microscopic edits. All pass with flying colors.

### Closing remark

If you are so eager to contribute, answer dem questions properly.

In the spirit of one of the pillars of TeX-SX : [Vote early and often!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/), **Review Late and Rarely!**

So, after all this tasteless rant, here is my actual problem; I'm tired of keeping track of wrongly closed questions or questions with threatening comments under them. I don't know any other way than actually pointing fingers to users which would cause even more bitter taste so question is how can we (assuming that I'm not the only one feeling this strange transition) reach out to these users without creating a primary school level snitching-to-mod game?

I really want to get the attention of those frequent-voting users because I think we can arrive to a better understanding (though it seems difficult if they are high on badges and euphoric on their name up on the The Most Awesome Reviewer list).

**Afteredit on an important detail** The reason why I seem to have a tone that targets individuals is because I don't expect the powers-that-be to unimplement this review system anytime soon. So the only way to change this situation is through reviewer behavior. Had this system not in place, they wouldn't be able to vote this quickly and erroneously. Hence while it is true that I speak mostly about reviewers, the target is indirectly and essentially these buttons that amplify and encourage careless reviewing behavior.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200168/why-is-rotate-useless-in-deluxetable#comment468307_200168

Comment: I tend not to eat breakfast; maybe that's the problem. But yeah, sorry, I've realized that I'm contributing to this problem a bit myself. I've been pretty busy over the last few months and haven't had that much time to ask or answer questions, so I thought reviewing would be a less time intensive way to actually contribute to the site. Which I guess has led to me taking less time on some reviews than I should have. Anyway, I think I'll take a break from reviewing for a while. Sorry everyone!

Comment: Good question! Maybe I'll answer later as I think to be responsible for roughly speaking 1.5k closing votes. Being here for more than 2 years, don't you think there has been a period in which many very experienced users slowed down a little bit their contribution to the site? It comes in my mind Andrew, lockstep, Alain, but there are more. Maybe, users arrived later, did not have the opportunity to get things in the way they were before just looking at what the "big guys" were doing and barely followed SX rules. What do you think?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Numbers are irrelevant. lockstep practically retagged the whole site without causing any controversy or annoyance. So he deserves all kind of authority or badge or whatever. But the issue is about whether we review as meticulously as him? Or randomly clicking buttons because the system gives us the chance to do so in the name of all active users. Exhaustion is a fair point I didn't think about that much. Let me chew it for a while.

Comment: Very good point! Honestly, I always thought that the differences in voting reflects somehow human nature of seeing things from different angles. Though, it's true that we need to keep in mind, and add to previous reasoning, the knowledge level of each user, which is obviously different. The point I totally share with you is the ridiculous amount of time in which questions are closed.

Comment: I've raised this 'higher up': I guess what you are talking about is primarily not individuals but rather how the system might encourage sub-optimal behaviours.

Comment: @JosephWright Not only encourage but also isolate them so that there is absolutely no way to avoid a handful of users taking over the entire community behavior with a few clicks of a button. Fixing the damage they cause is a major task; finding the questions, voting for reopening, even comforting the user that it was a mistake etc. We are much better off without this automated review screening. Note that auditing won't help here because we don't even see the review items anymore due to this weird selective redirecting system to particular users and it is self-reinforcing.

Comment: BTW, with respect to _if you don't obey my warning, I'll call my mod brother and he'll whoop yo ass_:  the mod team are very unlikely to do such a thing :-)

Comment: I think, fundamentally it boils down to providing an incentive for reviewing. One the one hand reviewing should be a selfless act to help improve the site. However, selfless acts would rarely succeed in this environment without some form of incentive (like a leader board, and badges).

Comment: ...perhaps another point to remember here is: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/914686). In fact, a [Skip incentive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/168244) has been mentioned on [meta.se], but it doesn't seem to be of interest in a larger community. Again, perhaps because it comes with another incentive...

Comment: @Werner We were doing just fine before this system arrived. And if you remember it was a much fluent practice both closing and opening the questions. Because more than 5 people were involved no matter which user it was. SO model is actually hurting many many satellites not only TeX-SX. Plus people can vote without even reading the question which is sheer nonsense. It might happen that someone understands the actual problem while the majority cannot see the culprit. These nuances are all swallowed by this automation.

Comment: @JosephWright Of course you won't, but bluffing is a very cunning practice.

Comment: @percusse Any comments which suggest that the mod team would act in the way suggested should I think get flagged

Comment: @AdamLiter As long as you invest time and care, you don't need to stop at all. I'm not trying to discourage people, quite the contrary please do but you don't need to rush. If it happens that you were not fast enough to mark so be it. That's what I'm doing.

Comment: @percusse I think a quick look around the main meta site suggests that there are issues even on the main site with the review queue system. However, whether we can get anything done about it I'm not so sure.

Comment: @JosephWright We can always deny specific people from doing the work if their work is done badly. I _don't want to push_ for such a repressive action, but if it's the only available way of making the review queues work better, so be it.

Comment: @tohecz As I understand it, the 'big picture' issue here is not the behaviour of a specific individual but the fact that the review queue system tends to encourage rapid reviewing as it's 'easy'. Thus it's a system issue, not a personal one.

Comment: @JosephWright Let me put it also in the question because that is indeed my issue here.

Comment: Indeed, the system before the review queues was working pretty well. To cast a close vote, questions had to be read first. So it wasn't that immediate as now. On the other hand, the system itself provides some balance: questions may get closed soon, but also reopened soon, provided that there are enough users to cast reopen votes. So I think percusse is right in his after-edit: everything depends on reviewers behaviour and that's something it is possible to train to some extent.

Comment: Wouldn't a solution to fast closing be some kind of *time-delay* till the Q comes up in the review queue? And also a delay to *close*/*delete*/etc to encourage actually reading the question and keeping the *trigger-happy* away?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino As a fairly active user, I would say that the one thing that will *discourage* my participation is if the site becomes perceived as being an unfriendly place, not whether there are too many questions that maybe should be closed. More and more I'm finding myself seeing closed questions and asking "Why?" (like percusse) and also seeing far too many "Please add a MWE" to questions that strictly speaking can be answered without. (There, I said it. :) )  Such behaviour does not contribute positively to the site IMO.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Agreed! I remember to have seen one of such comments asking mwe on a question on the line "which font is this one?". Totally non-sense! Though, if users have the feeling that their questions are closed too much quickly, I guess that is not contributing to make the place friendly.

Comment: *Lex Parsimoniae*: My plan is to inquiry the SX development team to remove the `review` subsystem from user-level access. At least, in order to make any decisions on a question, everybody needs to read it first. `:)`

Comment: @AlanMunn I would also add; *I don't even understand the need for this paranoid defense for open questions* other than duplicates. The proper way is going the extra mile to answer them not getting scared of. We are after all the opinionated bunch. We should know better unless the question really doesn't give in to any possible way of solving it.

Comment: @percusse -- i'm willing to 'fess up that i have, on occasion, voted to close a question, and later to reopen the same question.  in my defense, i note that in all cases i can think of, either the question was revised to add a new wrinkle, or someone provided enlightenment in a comment that made it obvious what was different about the question.  (and i'm perfectly willing to skip questions whose topic i know nothing about.  also to hunt for possible duplicates, to justify my reason for closing; but sometimes finding an item i *know* is there isn't easy.  i *love* the "frequently asked" list!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You weren't one of them don't worry. I like how you extensively argue about what is why.

Comment: Fwiw, my 2 cents: it's the whole system of the site that kind of promotes this behavior. I have run into [such a user as well](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193589/pgfplots-how-can-i-define-one-cycle-list-for-all-graphs-or-the-least-amount-p?noredirect=1#comment447302_193589) and he/she seems to vote to close a lot as well. However I still really like the site and the users on here. Stopped posting on askubuntu.com though because it is not very pleasant there.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I've done that too. Hunting for duplicates is not easy, for sure!

Comment: @Werner If this is happening with the relatively older users, I don't have any difficulty addressing them right away (valid also the other way around). But we can't reach to the reviewers anymore. They are like the old dudes in the balcony in Muppet Show. They dislike almost everything :)

Comment: @Johannes_B A cooldown period (after say 20 votes) is already in place on SO. Also, every once in a while, SO will put you to the test with a fake review; if you review it correctly, you get a message of the type: *Congratulations! That was a test; you passed!* Pity we don't have that on TeX.SX.

Comment: I don't know if I'm on percusse's list, but I'll confess my sins anyway: sometimes, I'm a bit too quick to close questions I deem unclear. I will change my ways and try to be more patient. However, I never have a problem with clicking *Skip* if I have a doubt.

Comment: I ask for MWEs *a lot*. But I think that the addition of an MWE improves a question in many cases even when it is not strictly required to answer it. First, it may well be that people here could complete code to produce an MWE but providing an MWE in the question makes it easier to answer and, yes, requires the questioner to make the effort required to create one. But, more than that, I think that an MWE makes many questions clearer even to those not 'in the know'. That is, the fact that a question is clear to an expert doesn't make it clear to everyone. An MWE can help greatly with that.

Comment: Also, I've almost completely given up reviewing on the grounds that I am never fast enough. I don't, frankly, see the point.

Comment: @cfr I agree MWE is great for questions. But asking is not the same as demanding. And it cannot be a preliminary if she's a new user. Effort required is not a known entity outside the Stackexchange network. And in my humble opinion it is ill-defined.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to ask a new user for an MWE provided some information is provided about what that means, of course. But, then, I think knowing how to create an MWE is the single most useful thing one can learn about TeX so perhaps I'm biased. Effort is ill-defined but questions which post an image and say 'please draw this for me, preferably in 3D' certainly demonstrate very little effort. In that kind of case, I don't think it is unhelpful to suggest somebody should have a bit of a go themselves. Also, an MWE often tells you what knowledge a user already has.

Comment: @cfr TeX world is not all about this site. People are used to forums where you elaborate 2 pages and in the last one you arrive to an understanding. Also what you are describing is the view of a resident not a person who is casually asking a TeX/TikZ question. Effort required is SO lingo and I don't think it is as valid here. What is the effort anyway? We know already see one of my meta questions that some people will answer it anyways. So why fake and pretend that we are all uniformly waiting for a MWE? I certainly don't (if I understand the question enough or I'm not extra grumpy that day)

Comment: I've obviously visited the wrong (or right) forums, in that case, as that's not been my experience. But I profoundly disagree about MWEs. I don't mostly think people should post MWEs for the benefit of this site. I think they should create MWEs because they are extraordinarily useful. If you know nothing about TeX, you can use an MWE to troubleshoot even though the cryptic error messages and log file mean nothing to you. That was so long before TeX SE existed and it works even if you know zilch about programming and almost nothing about TeX. The existence of sites like this makes MWEs less...

Comment: important. But sites like this can disappear, you can lose internet access,... but so long as you are using TeX at all, you can use MWEs to figure stuff out. It is not the fastest method. Its great advantage is that it is a purely mechanical process which anybody can learn. (Or anybody capable of using TeX - maybe not 18 month old children or cats.) This has nothing to do with TeX SE. (Maybe the term is TeX SE specific.)

Comment: @cfr Again, I agree about MWEs but it stops there. There is no **should**. We are not here to discipline people. In the same manner, if everyone read the manuals or even TeXbook there wouldn't any need for this site anyway. So the pedagogical superiority is a social artifact that we should definitely avoid here. Because both it's not something we possess over new users and also it's not our problem. If you don't post a MWE your chance of getting answers that are less useful increases but it doesn't hinder the act of asking a question.

Comment: I don't find it difficult to ignore bad questions and we sweep them later with the *Answer the Unanswered* sessions (which many of those reviewers never participate by the way). So in terms of bookkeeping, I don't see any relevance of the question quality. It obviously helps everyone and makes it more fun but that's about it in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that posting one should be a requirement for asking a question or that questions should be closed if they lack one. But one way of helping somebody who asks for help is to explain how they can help themselves. I think people should create them and include them. That is not at all the same as saying that the site should enforce any sort of requirement that they do so. I also think people should not generally break their promises. It does not follow that I think anybody has any business making them keep them. [I am not suggesting MWEs are a *moral* 'should'.]

Comment: @cfr Great, so we arrived to a common point that we agree about MWEs not being a requirement. That's one out of many items that I'm experiencing day-to-day review behavior essentially leading to the first close vote followed by the robo-review sniping. That's pretty much the bare essentials of this post.

Comment: I would distinguish cases in which MWE really helps and cases in which I think it absolutely unnecessary to ask for them. [See this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201394/13304). Admittedly is not a good one, but the OP asks explicitly "How can I get the following font in latex?". I really don't see how a MWE would help in such a case! In other cases instead they help, that's sure. Otherwise the best you can do is to have a look on the crystal ball, write your answer and hope your guess was ok. Maybe it is, or maybe the OP will politely answer that everything doesn't work. [...]

Comment: [...] And try to debug why it doesn't work if you don't know what distribution the OP has, which packages she loads and so on. To conclude, _when needed_, MWE are to me a way to keep quality in the site. Questions state clearly the problem, answers solve _that_ problem. Of course polite ways to ask for MWE are encouraged. Maybe we can revisit the `text building blocks` if they do not fit well anymore.

Comment: Espeacially the latest comments are related to [How about encouraging the users to provide MWE before asking questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4606)

Comment: @percusse -- "..., if everyone read the manuals or even TeXbook there wouldn't any need for this site anyway."  i disagree!  i've been at this gig longer than anyone else on this site, and i find it mighty useful!  maybe i don't ask a lot of questions, but that's largely because other people have the same questions, and there are a lot of knowledgeable participants who are able to answer (most of) them before i even look at the site in the morning.  and i'm a big fan of mnwe's (i'm facing a bug now that requires at least 4 variations to demonstrate).  onward with the "good bad example"!

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's the other way around. Insisting on MWE as a starting point to a user is imposing a way of working to a user that you like but maybe other don't. So I gave the manual example for that. If they had read the manual, they would see the available options but they don't and they ask here. Now if you push a comment under that question, `it's in the manual, go check it` would that be nice? They are not doing it anyway. It would become yet another hostile, stupid place if we start doing that. Every question can be answered by a comment. But actually making the answer is the contrib.

Comment: but @percusse -- what if it's *not* in the manual?  having written a few, and read a lot more, i know that's not always a reasonable answer, even for folks who *do* read documentation.  so, before i suggest referring to existing documentation, i try to check to make sure the answer is really there -- and am sometimes surprised.  then the goal of avoiding (apparent) hostility is probably what one should think of first.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm not implying anything with the example, I'm using that analogy to argue that MWE asking is not essential to any question. But we are pushing these block comments as if it is a prerequisite to survive without your question being closed without an answer. Did you know that the time that it takes to have a non-MWE question to be marked as unclear dropped to 15mins to 30mins?That's because the behavior is being reinforced, the more review you do, this stupid system opens more review chances for you. As you remember, we left questions open about a week until OP came back...

Comment: before this system is implemented

Comment: I agree with @cfr on the importance of MWEs. Actually, often enough, the very process of producing an MWE already puts the OP on the path to a solution, makes her realise a mistake, etc.

Comment: @jubobs me too. Read on. It's not about mwes. It's about continuously asking for it for no reason. See my answer. Apparently everyone picks up the part they like

Comment: I eat randomly chosen food for breakfast.

Comment: @Ohmyghost Food cannot be random by definition.

Comment: @ohmyghost Food is not enumerable.

Comment: @Ohmyghost not enumerable -> no list.

Comment: My fingers got injured, I cannot type.

Answer (score 30):

'Executive summary' of the following answer:

- The key aim of reading questions is to help the asker
- Voting to close is thus (usually) something to do after comments or similar to improve questions have failed
- Rapid closing is ideally aimed at clear cases such as questioner agreeing, spam, massively off-topic, *etc.*
- Minimal working examples (MWEs) are a useful part of this process but are not a 'requirement' nor always needed to understand a question
- Asking for a MWE is partly a way of helping the questioner help themselves: once they can do this, they are likely to be able to solve more problems themselves
- Keep the questioner in mind: we were all beginners once

---

Quite what a 'real' answer here would be I'm not sure, but I think a summary of the consensus from the comments would be in some way useful. Before I do that, though, I'd like to observe that the question has a good number of votes (23 at the time of writing) and so presumably the concern raised is shared by a spectrum of 'active' users. (We know of course that votes on meta are a bit tricky to interpret.)

There seem to me to be two parts to the question: one part about closing votes, a second about comments on questions, and both have interesting comments here. I'll therefore try to each both of them and summarise.

In terms of voting to close, the general feeling seems to be that there is no need to rush to vote to close questions. Over time, some questions can indeed be closed, for example when clarity is never achieved, the problem clearly resolves to a minor issue (typo, *etc.*), or for many other reasons. However, that doesn't mean that they have to be closed quickly. The latter action is something that the review queues do seem to encourage: they tend to pick up questions not long after asking, and it's then rather easy to vote to close without giving things time. In particular, and perhaps one that we might get the dev team to consider, it's notable that the buttons to vote to close questions in the queue come at the top of the page, making it rather easy to vote without reading the question, any comments, and answers. Moving the button might be a good idea!

As with many things on the site, there are badges for reviewing, and there is at least some likelihood that a certain amount of motivation to review quickly comes from this. That's not just been raised as a concern here: it's come up on the main meta site too. At the moment, I can't say I see any change by the Powers being likely, so we have to adopt a sensible approach to reviewing (see below).

On the comments front, the main concern is about asking minimal working examples (MWEs). Experience suggests that most of the time a MWE is useful in dealing with a question: they help track down errors, give clear demonstrations of what's happening and so on. At the same time, there are perfectly clear questions that don't require a MWE. Importantly, asking for a MWE is a *request* to the questioner to help us to help them: it's certainly not a requirement for asking a question. Hopefully the [Text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) get this about right, but we can always revise them. (Of course, everyone is free to write comments however they like: the pre-written text is just there as a handy reference, really.)

On this area, it's perhaps worth noting something that happened when the close reasons got revised to drop the old 'too localized' and bring in 'unclear' plus custom 'off topic' reasons. The mod team can add a small number of custom 'off topic' reasons to the standard list, and as part of the roll-out the developers added some suggestions. One they put was 'off topic as there is no MWE' (or words to that effect), which the mod team didn't adopt. Over all, lacking a MWE is fine if the question can be understood, so the mod team reasoned that questions which need a MWE but never get one are 'unclear' and *not* 'off-topic'.

---

The overall approach that's been taken to date on the site to trying to improve 'sub-optimal' questions rather than closing them: after all, the idea of reading questions is to try to help the person asking. As such, the approach most users have taken is that voting to close is something to do *after* you've tried to guide the questioner to make things clear, and only when that seems to have failed. Of course, there are questions which are massively off-topic, where the OP agrees to them being closed and so on, and those can all get dealt with quickly. For a lot of questions, though, what is best is a bit of patience in helping the questioner to help us to help them!

Comment: Great summary *and* answer!

Comment: i agree with Werner.  but i would suggest making an "executive summary" at the top, listing the essential points, followed by the commentary, so that "casual" readers have the option of not having to read through the whole answer to determine what's important for "adjusting" their behavior.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Would that essentially mean moving the last paragraph to the top?

Comment: @JosephWright -- moving the last paragraph to the top might do.  but maybe an alternate approach, presenting those points as a list.  (as much as i hate such "executive summaries", they do have their uses, and capturing the attention of readers with short attention spans is probably the most valuable.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've gone for a list: hope it helps.

Comment: @JosephWright -- super!  the only thing i might suggest is a brief comment to the effect that, in appropriate cases, it might be worth pointing out to a user that constructing a minimal example can help *them* isolate the problem and its cause on their own -- a skill-building experience.  only in fewer words.  (i *always* use too many words; i can only defer to mark twain and his comment about how brevity takes more time.)

Answer (score 17):

As we have seen from the comments, every detail leads to another full blown discussion and I am not the TeX-SX correspondant so I'll try to be a user again.

Because there is user involvement that might lead to confrontation and since we are extremely avoiding it, I have to be very careful with the sentences I am using. Otherwise it starts to get dissected and my point gets lost. Since it has some upvotes and zero reviewer answers here.

Wait actually there is a cute one but not so useful; I initially mentioned that instead of chasing down close votes I would rather prefer having my usual TikZ porn and this is a response

> I have no time to discuss with you, sorry. I will not answer your question on meta. Good luck with your TikZ porn. I am not deciding in the name of everyone... I am rewiewing in my proper name, of course.

---

Lovely. So coming back to the essential reason of this whole long, long post is this last bit in the response. But anyway no need to make it personal;

1. Reviews are not our personal toys, they are, no matter how terribly implemented, here for site moderation and consistency.  They define what is proper and suitable and what is not. They are also exemplary for future visitors to give an idea why a question is closed or why something is edited, retagged. You can't be on your own clicking buttons and not taking null responsibility. But from the look of it, we have no incentive to handle this so this opens for a possibility of everybody hanging around according to their leisure. This is a stronger version of the subtle question I've posted initially. So now we can put it on the table more suitably. This would undoubtedly cause a lot of trouble. If we are smelling the smoke, it won't help if we keep saying that it's still not that hot around here.
2. Asking for MWE is, with all my respect, getting super-annoying. Here is a simple test; ask yourself this **Am I going to answer this question if the user actually includes a MWE?** If your answer is no then don't bother commenting. The potential answerer can do the same. You are really really not helping. And it is not making anything easier. Because if you see it under every question, it loses its effect (already lost but nevermind).
3. The questions are unclear if the OP responds to and still doesn't include information. If two users are interacting, it's not your call to decide on the question. Stop marking every question as unclear. They are not. There is no time limit for a question it can be open for years.
4. If you will invoke a *I'm keeping the site tidy* argument, then start joining our Answer the Unanswered sessions. There you will have ample amount of happy-trigger satisfaction. No need to slam the questions to the users' faces.

I hope this clarifies a bit about my point. Please come to the chat instead of commenting to this one because apparently this post didn't make any impact so no need for further surgery. Of course you are free to do so but I'm a little reluctant to reply to avoid extensive commenting (see above).

Comment: I am *so* with you on that MWE point; some people seem to be asking for MWE's without any intent of answering the question.

Comment: on MWE as I've commented elsewhere I'm not that fond of any of the "text blocks": posting boilerplate comments never seems that useful. If I do ask for a MWE I usually state that every question should have one, as that's a reasonable approximation to the truth, but I answer questions without a MWE if answer doesn't need a test (or making one isn't too much work)

Comment: ++++1 for point number 2.  I think all of us understand the value of MWEs, but they are most relevant when someone is getting an error or an output they don't understand. If someone is asking things like "How do a make a table a single cell shaded grey?" or "How do I read a CSV file in LaTeX?" asking for a MWE at best gives everyone some code to copy. Such questions are perfectly clear without a MWE even if adding one might make it slightly faster for someone to answer.

Comment: TikZ pr0nZ FTW! `:)`